# How to debug WINE?

Tags: wine, debugging

I've been using WINE for years for a program called CLUEWIN. This is a pretty simple win32 application (a dictionary). It has no noteworthy features and has always worked, for around 20 years. The CLUEWIN application itself has remained unchanged for this time.

Now, it has stopped working. I thought this was just due to a quirk with the current system state that would resolve itself after an update. However, now I've updated wine and the issue still persists.

This is wine-9.1 on Arch Linux.

This is what I get when I strace the offending CLUEWIN.EXE process:

```
recvmsg(18, {msg_namelen=2291756}, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(18, {msg_namelen=2291804}, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(18, {msg_namelen=2291708}, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(18, {msg_namelen=2291756}, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(12, [{iov_base="<\1\2\0\t\2 \2;\3\3\0\242\0 \2k\0!\0", iov_len=20}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) = 20
recvmsg(12, {msg_namelen=2291740}, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(12, {msg_namelen=2291788}, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

I'm not sure if this is normal behavior or not. There are no errors. If I just run wine manually with the path to CLUEWIN.EXE specified it prints no errors or warnings.

How can I go about debugging this?

Comment: Start with a fresh wine prefix. If it doesn't help, try earlier wine releases which you know worked.